# Changing values of variable inside a nested for loop in python when writing to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, variables, nested-loops

I want to change the values written inside the f.write function for the j loop to change every time the i loop runs. i.e. the values -1200.0 and 90.0 should alternatively become 0.0 and 0.0 every time the i loop runs. The code is as follow:

```
f = open('workfile.txt', 'w')

for i in range(1, 152):
    f.write('BEGIN PERIOD ' + str(i) + '\n')

    for j in range(6,36):
        f.write(str(j) + ' 1 -1200.0 90.0' + '\n')

    f.write('END PERIOD ' + str(i) + '\n')

f.close()
```

The output I am getting is as following:

```
BEGIN PERIOD 1
6 1 -1200.0 90.0
7 1 -1200.0 90.0
8 1 -1200.0 90.0
9 1 -1200.0 90.0
...
35 1 -1200.0 90.0
END PERIOD 1
```

And similarly until BEGIN PERIOD 151 ... END PERIOD 151. Howwever, I want the values -1200.0 and 90.0 to become 0.0 and 0.0 in every alternative iteration for i loop. So the code should look something like this:

```
BEGIN PERIOD 1
6 1 -1200.0 90.0
7 1 -1200.0 90.0
8 1 -1200.0 90.0
9 1 -1200.0 90.0
...
35 1 -1200.0 90.0
END PERIOD 1

BEGIN PERIOD 2
6 1 0.0 0.0
7 1 0.0 0.0
8 1 0.0 0.0
9 1 0.0 0.0
...
35 1 0.0 0.0
END PERIOD 2

BEGIN PERIOD 3
6 1 -1200.0 90.0
7 1 -1200.0 90.0
8 1 -1200.0 90.0
9 1 -1200.0 90.0
...
35 1 -1200.0 90.0
END PERIOD 3
```

And so on.
Could someone please help me out with this? Thank you

Comment: Turn `f.write(str(j) + ' 1 -1200.0 90.0' + '\n')` into: `f.write(f"{j} 1 {['-1200.0 90.0', '0.0 0.0'][i%2==0]}\n")`

Comment: @PaulM. What is the name of the concept you use in the f-string? Seems like some conditional statement in form of lists. Never saw it before.

Comment: @AnsFourtyTwo It doesn't have a special name or anything. It's just a list literal containing two strings, and then I'm accessing the index `i%2==0` of that list. A boolean expression will be implicitly cast to an integer in this context.

Comment: Ok, got it. Nice hacky way of circumventing the `if-else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first suggest you to use `with open()`, as it is considered more pythonic. Having said that:

```
with open('workfile.txt', 'w') as f:
for i in range(1, 152):
    f.write('BEGIN PERIOD ' + str(i) + '\n')
    
    if i % 2 == 1:
        x = '-1200.0'
        y = '90.0'
    else:
        x = '0.0'
        y = '0.0'
        
    for j in range(6, 36):
        str_append = '1 %s %s' % (x, y)
        f.write(str(j) + str_append + '\n')
    
    f.write('END PERIOD ' + str(i) + '\n')
```

Comment: An improvement, although not absolutely required, would be to use f-strings.